# SonataAdminBundle - Form View: add an Entity composed of a Primary Key of 2 fields

Tags: symfony

I'm in a real trouble.

I'm using the Sonata Admin Bundle and I need help about The Form View (https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/the_form_view.html).

My database is so structured: in ProductsCatalogue the **primary Key is 'code'+'variant'**. The relation is 1toMany.

- Table ProductsCatalogue: id, code, variant, description
- Table Stocks: id, serial number, position

**The problem**: In the Add Form of a new element of Stock I need to select the related product. In order to do it I need to select before the code, and then the variant. The list of the variants should be update after the choiche of the code. Done it, I have an unique product selected.

So now I know how to insert in the right way the first field (code) but I don't know how to generate the second one (variant).

> $formMapper
>           // ...
>           ->add('category', 'entity', [
>               'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Category',
>               'property' => 'name',
>           ])
>       ;

Anyone can help me please?

Thank you very much and have a good day!
Marco.